# Not able to get Firebase crashlytics in react native android appliction

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-crash-reporting

I am trying to add Firebase Crashlytics in react native application. I have added all the dependencies as per firebase console suggestion but I am not getting any crash report on the console. I have implemented crash reports as per the native android code.

Comment: are u use react-native-firebase?

Comment: Yes but I am following android native firebase implementation. I think its same in react native and native android